# Rewriting the polynomial $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - xz - yz$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am wondering whether it is possible to factorize/rewrite the following with Newton's identities (or some other algorithm) where the polynomial is given by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - xz - yz$.
I am trying to gain a full grasp of Newton's identities or some algorithm for simplifying the polynomials.

Comment: You can write this as $\frac12(x-z)^2+\frac12(x-y)^2+\frac12(y-z)^2$. However, that is not really a factorization.

Comment: @wythagoras Oh, sorry, I didnt exactly mean factorization then. May I ask what is the best way to see such a way to rewrite a polynomials (in terms of things to look for or best yet an algorithm to do so) ?

Comment: Well, I only saw/knew this one because I used it a while ago to prove that the expression $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz$  is always larger than zero.

Comment: Okay thats fair, it is the same case for me as well for the same proof where I ran into some trouble because I didnt exactly know how to rewrite the polynomial in the way you stated it (thats why I am looking for a possible algorithm to generalize)

Comment: I'm afraid there is not really an algorithm.

Comment: It's mostly just experience and luck. There is no single "trick" to spotting such rewritings.